# Visual Studio 2012 Save Projects to Cloud

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have searched google but cannot find a solution that will allow me to store my projects in a cloud so I can easily access them from my computers that have visual studio 2012

Answer (score 4):

You can use  [Visual Studio Team Services](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-online-overview-vs) (formerly Visual Studio Online, Team Foundation Service).  The basic account is free for up to five users.  You can use TFS or Git as your version control.

[GitHub](https://github.com/) is also free for Git repositories.